# Connecting two collections in meteor (comments on posts)

Tags: javascript, git, mongodb, meteor, forum

I made two collections, one for posts and one for comments. Now, everything is working fine for now except Every comment show on every post. I do not know how to connect one comment with "his" post. I thought to save id of post inside his comment but I don't know how to connect those two together later. Here is link of my app on GitHub (it's small app and it has clear code). Thanks!
[enter link description here](https://github.com/dale032/predlozi-GIT.git)

**Main collection for posts**

```
    Predlozi = new Mongo.Collection('BazaPredlozi');

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.startup(function () {

   }); 

    Meteor.publish('BazaPredlozi', function() {
      return Predlozi.find();
    });



   /************************************/
        Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {      

              user.profile = options.profile ? options.profile : {};
              user.profile.неискоришћениГласови = 3;
              user.profile.nivo = 'smrtnik';
                 return user;
        });       

/********************************/
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (Meteor.isClient) {


    Meteor.subscribe('BazaPredlozi');   


    Template.body.helpers({
      Podaci: function() {
        return Predlozi.find();
      },  
      YouShallNotPass: function () {
       var user = Meteor.user();
       var nivo = user && user.profile && user.profile.nivo;
       return nivo === 'supermen';
  },

});

  Template.UnosPredloga.events({

    'submit .Prijava': function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        var naslov = event.target.наслов.value;
        var opis = event.target.опис.value;
        var korisnik = Meteor.user()._id;

          Predlozi.insert ({
             наслов : naslov,
             опис : opis,
             унео: korisnik ,
             Број_Гласова: 0,         
             Време_Уноса: new Date()
          });      
          event.target.наслов.value = "";
          event.target.опис.value = "";
          return false;        
     }
  });   

// -------------
}
```

**Main HTML**

```
<head>
  <title>Видео конференције</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
<!-- -->
  <div class="kontejner">
      <header>
        <h1>Пријаве за видео-конференцију</h1>  
        {{#if currentUser}}       
         {{> UnosPredloga}}
         {{/if}}

      </header>
          {{> templateSkočko}}  
      <ul style="border: 3px solid pink; margin: 5px;">
          {{#each Podaci}} 
            <div style="border: 3px solid red; margin: 5px;">            
             {{> PodaciT}}

           {{#if currentUser}} 
               {{> glasajDugme}}
               {{> KomentarForma}}
                   {{#each komentari}}
                    {{> PrikazKomentara}}
                   {{/each}}

           {{/if}}     

             {{#if YouShallNotPass}}
              {{> obrišiDugme}}
              {{/if}}

            </div>
          {{/each}}          
      </ul>
  </div>
<!-- --> 
<div style="background-color: blue; color: red;"> {{> loginButtons}} </div>
</body>
```

**Post insert template**

```
<template name="UnosPredloga">
    <form class="Prijava">
            <input type="text" name="наслов" placeholder="Наслов" id="NaslovPredloga" required >
            <input type="text" name="опис" placeholder="Опис" id="OpisPredloga" required>           
            <input type="submit" value="Пошаљи" id="DugmeZaUnosPredloga">
         </form>
</template>
```

**Display post template**

```
<template name="PodaciT">
   <div>
       <div class="prikaze"><p>Наслов:</p>{{наслов}}</div>  
       <div class="prikaze"><p>Опис:</p>{{опис}}</div> 
       <div class="prikaze"><p>Написао:</p>{{унео}}</div>
       <div class="prikaze"><p>Гласова:</p>{{Број_Гласова}}</div>    

     <!--  <div class="prikaze"><p>Унето:</p>{{Време_Уноса}}</div> -->
        </div>
</template>
```

**Comment collection**

```
Komentari = new Mongo.Collection('KomentariKorisnika');

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.startup(function () {

   }); 

    Meteor.publish('KomentariKorisnika', function() {
      return Komentari.find();
    });

/********************************/
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (Meteor.isClient) {


    Meteor.subscribe('KomentariKorisnika');   


    Template.body.helpers({
      komentari: function() {
        return Komentari.find();
      }, 
});

  Template.KomentarForma.events({

    'submit .KomentarNaPredlog': function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
          Komentari.insert ({
             коментар : event.target.datKomentar.value,
             коментарисао: Meteor.user()._id,         
             Време_Уноса: new Date(),
             ИДпредлогаКојемКоментарПрипада: this._id,
          });      
          event.target.datKomentar.value = "";
          return false;        
     }
  });   

// -------------
}
```

**Comment input teplate**

```
<template name="KomentarForma">

    <form class="KomentarNaPredlog">
            <input type="text" name="datKomentar" placeholder="Коментар" id="komentarčić" required >                    
            <input type="submit" value="Коментариши" id="DugmeZaUnosPredloga">
         </form>

</template>
```

**Display comments template**

```
    <template name="PrikazKomentara">
<div>
    <div class="prikaze"><p>Коментар:</p>{{коментар}}</div>
    <div class="prikaze"><p>Коментарисао:</p>{{коментарисао}}</div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: The comment should have his own id and the foreign id of the post it belongs to.

Comment: Ok, I'll easily make him to take ID of the post he belongs to put how later to make him be just next to that one post?

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter your 'comments' collection for each post. If you have multiple subscriptions for the same collection, their data is merged into one client-side collection.

If you post the relevant parts of your code, we might help you more. Please note that adding a GitHub URL doesn't count as posting relevant code.

Comment: Just post the relevant parts. Like, how you subscribe to this kind of data, and how your code renders it. Two or three functions / templates is a good start.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your language, and I'm not good with Blaze templates either, but I think `komentari` should go to `KomentarForma`'s helpers, and be filtered for each post. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that properly in Blaze, since I use React mainly.